# PKContact in iOS 9 missing street

Tags: ios, objective-c, applepay, passkit

I'm doing an Apple Pay integration using this new delegate method in `PKPaymentAuthorizationViewControllerDelegate` on iOS 9:

`paymentAuthorizationViewController:didSelectShippingContact:completion`

This provides a `PKContact` argument which has a shipping address in the form of an `CNPostalAddress` object.

No matter what address is provided (even the demo ones from the simulator), the street is always empty.

E.g:

`<CNPostalAddress: 0x7fbf9aed8bd0: street=, city=Hillsborough, state=CA, postalCode=94010, country=, countryCode=us, formattedAddress=(null)>`

Is this an iOS bug? Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the address that is returned is always partial and this isn't documented well by Apple. See here:

[Loading Apple Pay Shipping Address No Street](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26518767/loading-apple-pay-shipping-address-no-street)